# facebook-android-sdk error: publish_actions being required to post a share dialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, fbsdksharedialog

I have required publish_actions to my application in order to publish in users wall, but it was denied because (it was said) Facebook does not require publish_actions.

But I am trying to share a picture through the following code using Share Dialog:

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(bitmapLogoPhoto)
                .setCaption("Teste")
                .build();

        SharePhotoContent photoContent = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();

        //shareDialog.show(photoContent, ShareDialog.Mode.FEED);

        shareDialog.show(photoContent,ShareDialog.Mode.WEB);
```

...and ,even though it works with test users, I am getting the following error message from Facebook when using a real user :

> {FacebookGraphResponseException: (#200) Requires extended permission:
>   publish_actions httpResponseCode: 403, facebookErrorCode: 200,
>   facebookErrorType: OAuthException, message: (#200) Requires extended
>   permission: publish_actions}

What is the problem? How can I make it work properly?